# Button press not registered in [UnityTest] but is registered in [Test]

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, nunit, unity-test-tools

I have several tests (~50) for my game and finally got to the point to start testing classes that require input from the player. When I wrote my tests for the `Gamepad` and `Keyboard` + `Mouse` inputs every test passed properly but they were using the `[Test]` attribute and not `[UnityTest]` attribute.

Now that I'm trying to test button press with `[UnityTest]` it refuses to register it, neither with `Set(_gamepad.rightShoulder, 1);` neither with `Press(_gamepad.rightShoulder);` For curiosity, I tried the same test with the regular `[Test]` attribute and there it registered the button press.

Is this a known limitation for the `[InputTestFixture]` attribute or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using `InputSystem v1.4.4` and the code that I was trying to test was the following:

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator Shoot() {
    var bullets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Bullet");
    Assert.IsEmpty(bullets);
    Set(_gamepad.rightShoulder, 1);
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    bullets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Bullet");
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(bullets);
}
```

The Shooting controller is setup before, so it should run its `Update()` after yielding a  `new WaitForFixedUpdate()`. This was checked while debugging but the problem is the `_gamepad.rightShoulder` not being pressed.

Comment: You might need to use InputSystem to simulate the button press. 
`InputSystem.QueueStateEvent(_gamepad, new GamepadState().WithButton(GamepadButton.RightShoulder));`

and release later.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result is the same